# Дать доступ на запись asp.net приложению на хостинге

Tags: c#, asp.net, хостинг, доступ

Я - новичок в ASP.NET да и в web-программировании в целом, сейчас написал небольшое приложение-сайт и разместил его на хостинге. Но проблема в том, что некоторые контролы пытаются при инициализации создать в папке App_Data свои временные папки, а сервер им говорит, что прав то у них маловато для таких поступков... Как эти права приложению можно дать и вообще как управляться с правами доступа в Asp.net приложениях?

Comment: Это не в коде, это нужно смотреть конкретного хостера, что он разрешает (и настраивать руками). Щас же облака и всё такое: никто не хочет давать просто так ресурсы. IOPсы - это деньги, гигабайты - это деньги, оперативка - это деньги, отправить почту - это сервис (деньги) и так далее.

Comment: хостинг smarterasp.net, но вот что там настраивать вообще не представляю

Comment: С этим конкретным не сталкивался, но можете попробовать почитать их knowledge base или создать тикет. Либо подождите, может кто объявится знакомый с этим хостером.

Comment: что на этот вопрос отвечает вам ваш хостер?

Comment: пока хранит молчание

Comment: предложил вместо того контрола что есть использовать ftp

Comment: Через FTP ставите папке app_data права на запись, должно помочь.

Comment: Попробую, все равно вариантов других нет.

Comment: *"предложил вместо того контрола что есть использовать ftp"* - **бегите оттуда!**

Comment: Бежать нет смысла. Сейчас я все равно учусь, а хостинг дал аж целых 60 дней бесплатно. Кончатся - уйду.